# Linux: C++: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost_serialization

Tags: c++, linux, serialization, boost, g++

When I try to build some application with linking boost's library libboost_serialization.so, I have this error message:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost_serialization
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the output from ldconfig:

```
linux-rxa13:/usr/lib64 # ldconfig -p | grep serialization
        libboost_wserialization.so.1.46.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization.so.1.46.1
        libboost_wserialization.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization.so
        libboost_serialization.so.1.46.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so.1.46.1
        libboost_serialization.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so
```

And this is command line to build test application:

```
g++ -o "m" m.o -L/usr/lib64 -llibboost_serialization
```

I've searched for the solution to this problem, but I haven't found it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't put in the `lib`: `-lboost_serialization`

Answer (score 1):

I removed the "lib" from `-llibboost_serialization` and that worked for me. So it ended up being:

```
 -lboost_serialization
```